# Sync local and remote ms access db

Tags: database, ms-access, synchronization, database-replication

My client has a local MS Access database, he will be working on it locally, then he wants to sync it with another one on a remote server.

what is the best way to sync his changes to the online DB, or is there a way to open the online DB from MS Access ?

Thanks

Comment: can be done through a script or something ?

Answer (score 0):

One of my customers gave me the access to his server through VPN. Once the connection is etablished, I can see the connection by entering `\\192.168.xx.yy` (with appropriate values for xx and yy) in the windows explorer. Through the context menu of the connection symbol you can then map this to a drive letter and work with the mdb's as if they were on your local computer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the case here.